# Convert Think script (within x bars) to pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, pine-script-v4, thinkscript

Im trying to convert Think script to pine script.

Here is the Think Script i am wanting to convert...

```
      High crosses above Highest("data" = HIGH, "length" = 240)[1] within 60 bars
```

I want to know how to convert the "within 60 bars" part for pine script.

What i want to achieve in pine script is...

```
      x condition has happened within last x bars

      or

      Condition "within 60 bars"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of bars since the last time a condition was `true` using the `ta.barssince()` function and then compare it to 60:

```
counter = ta.barssince(yourCondition)
if counter < 60
    // do something
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Can i plot a shape after the "if counter < 60" ?